Clang in vs2022 does not show progress
I am trying to use clang cl toolset in visual studio 2022. But it seems only to show warnings and errors when building. It does not show any file currently compiling like msvc toolset.
Just create a new command line project, switch to clang tool chain (clang 17) and compile your program. It does not show the file(s) which are currently compiled. Does have anyone any idea?

Try adjusting the build output verbosity settings in Visual Studio. Go to "Tools" > "Options" > "Projects and Solutions" > "Build and Run", and set the "MSBuild project build output verbosity" to "Detailed" or "Diagnostic". This may provide more information during the build process, including the currently compiling files.

@ZhennZhang this does not work as expected. The outout should be like default (minimal) like v143 toolset. It does not work if the project was generated and build through by cmake

I tested it on my own machine, using Clang Toolset and VS v143 Toolset in VS2022. The output of the project built by these two methods is about the same, and I attach my screenshots. You can give me a comment to tell me what you want to know.
[1]Clang toolset: https://i.sstatic.net/lWQwkp9F.png
[2]vs toolset: https://i.sstatic.net/bZaJW1SU.png

@ZhennZhang its not the same. clang does not show the source files while compiling

It suddenly started happening; did you resolve this?

no, still the same Problem. It happens using cmake too (-T "CLang")
